# image blurring and focus ROI with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, effects

I have some ROIs (Region Of Interest) inside a jpeg image in which I'd like to focus user attention. I come up with a solution in which my site shows a blurred version of the image and then dynamically (upon certain events) it removes the blurring over a specific ROI.

How can I do so using HTML/Javascript/JQuery? Unfortunately HTML5 is not an option!

Comment: I forgot, ROIs are specified by X,Y coordinates and Radius length (ROIs are circles)

Comment: you could have the blurredimage as the background, then in the foreground have a div that has a background fo the non-blured image, just move that div and the position of the non-blurred image around as needed over the blurred image to give the effect of one part of it not being blured. sadly, you'll be restricted to squares in browsers that don't support rounded borders.

Comment: if html5 is not an option, what is? what are your support requirements?

Comment: Your solution seems promising but how to align the image of the foreground div with the background image? You know what I mean?

Comment: Ok, got it, moving the div and the foreground image accordingly...

Comment: I can deal with PHP/MySQL/HTML4/Javascript/jQuery. Going HTML5 is dangerous as I could lose some users, isn't it?